# win-sshfs disconnects after period inactivity, have to remount

Tags: sshfs

I've installed `win-sshfs (typical install)` on my `Windows 7` and when I leave for lunch and come back (around an hour), the mounted drive has been lost and it screws up my editor session.

The only way to restore connection is to unmount and mount again, which can take up to a minute and a half with no messages as to why it failed or what it's doing.

Any solution for this?

I tried SFTP Net Drive Free but because it uses SFTP, searches are extremely slow, taking 10 times longer than win-sshfs.

Comment: Im going to guess this is the ssh timeout on the server you are connecting to, so my guess no - withough changing the ssh server settings. Unless there is some option for a keepalive in win-sshfs or some other FUSE package.

Comment: [Old issue here](https://code.google.com/p/win-sshfs/issues/detail?id=27) and a recommendation to use the `NetworkDrive` option in `Sshfs.exe.config` but it seems that didnt work in Win7... may or may not have been fixed. There are also mentions of just working around by using something that will perform a minimal operation like a `touch` on the remote server to work as a kind of keepalive.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a tunnel using a **putty** before connecting the drive. Putty has the functionality you need. Instead of the remote server, you will connect to the local port, for example localhost:40000.

**win-sshfs** -> localhost: 40000-> **putty** tunnel -> remote ssh.

Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Note that plink would be better suited for this than putty.

Answer (score 0):

@prodigitalson points a good idea. For example, you can use Git bash and execute something like `while true; do touch /a; sleep 1; done &` (I mount the remote directory at `A:`), then keep Git bash open and now the mounted driver won't disconnect.